# Add line in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, newline

I have two texboxes (1, 2) and I'm trying to make it so that when I press enter in TextBox1 it changes row/line in Textbox2 and keeps the text that already was there. Any suggestions? Oh, and vbCrLf doesn't work.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown 
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then 
         TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf 
         TextBox1.Text = "" 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Show the code you have.

Comment: Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
```

To this:

```
TextBox2.Text &= TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf
```

You need to concatenate the new string to the existing text, your current code overwrites it. Also, make sure Textbox2 is set to **Multiline True** in the properties.

Comment: @BatmanTheLord: [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) is a better option for modern VB.NET development.

Answer (score 1):

You keep *replacing* the existing text in TextBox2.

Use the AppendText instead:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
  TextBox2.AppendText(TextBox1.Text & Environment.NewLine)
  TextBox1.Text = ""
End If
```